# Road overlapping - ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, topology, overlapping-features

I have a road feature class (in illustrations shown in gray color), each object in the attribute table has a "road_width" field with a numeric value, what width the road is. This feature class has over 1,300 places where there is a topology error, where the areas overlap. I exported the overlapping areas to a separate feature class (in the illustrations shown in red color)  I can't calculate the real road shape area because there are overlapping areas, so shape area doubles. What I want to do, I will show in the illustrations. 
[image: photo1]

I want every overlapping area to be cut (removed) from a road object with a smaller value for the "road_width" attribute and attached to a road object with a higher value for the "road_width" attribute. 
in the case shown in the illustration, the marked, overlapping area will be cut (removed) from the road object which has a value 5.5 for the "road_width" field and will be attached to the road object which has a value 6 for the "road_width" field.

In the event that the overlapping area is between road objects that have the same value for the "road_width" attribute, the overlapping area will be cut (removed) from any of these two objects and attached to any of these two objects.

Example:

[image: photo2]

I need a solution in ModelBuilder.

Comment: Interesting problem!  I might start by erasing the overlaps layers from your road polygons (erase tool).  I'm not sure how I would decide which roads to merge the overlap onto.  I take it that you need to calculate the road area for each individual road?

Comment: I have to calculate the sum of areas for each type of road width. So the sum of "Shape_Area" for road objects that have value "5" for a field "road_width", then the sum of "Shape_Area" for road objects that have value "5.5" for a field "road_width",  and so on. If I started calculating these areas now, doubled values would come out, due to overlapping objects. First the topology problem must be solved in such a way as showed in figures, and using ModelBuilder.

Comment: I see.  Can you group the road lines by width before creating the buffers?  That would remove a lot of overlaps.  You could also then delete all overlaps of smaller widths on bigger widths.  Then it would be a matter of deleting overlaps between roads with the same widths, but that should be taken care of if you can merge the roads on width before buffering.

Comment: What does your model so far look like?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  I think the comments by @jbalk should help you to focus your question and provide precise details of what you have tried so far, and where you are currently stuck.

Comment: I've already built the correct model, thank you @jbalk for your help